# sqlalchemy count(), give zero if no lines exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to count the number of rows in a join statement

```
counts = models.Table.query.join(subquery, func.date(subquery.c.date)==func.date(models.Table.date))
counts = counts.add_columns(subquery.c.count)
counts = counts.add_columns(models.Table.date).distinct(models.Table.date).group_by(models.Table.date)
counts = counts.order_by(models.Table.date.desc()).paginate(page, 7, False)
```

where the subquery is defined as

```
subquery = db.session.query(models.Table2.date, models.Table2.id, func.count(models.Table2.id).label("count")).group_by(models.Table2.date).subquery()
```

I want the number of rows in Table for each date in Table2. The current selection skips over any date which has zero rows in Table2?
thanks
carl

Comment: Have you tried rowcount ?http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html